# AWS MediaLive variable data identifiers are not resolved

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live, aws-mediapackage

AWS MediaLive supports variable data identifiers as per the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/variable-data-identifiers.html

I have a CMAF MediaPackage endpoint and I set the segment prefix as `segment_$rc$_$w$_$h$`.

I'm expecting `$rc$`, `$w$` and `$h$` to resolve to bitrate, resolution width and height in the manifest file.

The main playlist file has contents as below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=464472,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=360812,RESOLUTION=416x234,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CODECS="avc1.4D400D,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio_0"
master_1.m3u8
```

and the segment files have contents as below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="../segment_$rc$_$w$_$h$_video_1_track_1670065154_csid_41e44badf4ef47a1bb8813103e090d47_2_init.mp4"
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-12-22T19:08:03.801Z
#EXTINF:6.006,
../segment_$rc$_$w$_$h$_video_1_1.mp4?m=1640199778
```

As you can see, the segment url's appear as `../segment_$rc$_$w$_$h$_video_1_1.mp4`.

Any idea why the variables are not resolved?
Am I using this in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPackage supports a different set of substitution variables versus MediaLive. The currently supported manifest and segment name variables for MediaPackage are listed in the MediaPackage user guide found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/cfigs-dash-manset.html

If you want to see see additional variables supported, I encourage you to log a Feature Request from the 'Feedback' button found in the lower left corner of the MediaPackage web console. The service team reads these suggestions and the most popular ones do get actioned.